# How to properly connect cloudant + sag

Tags: cloudant, sag

I'm working in getting a connection to cloudant done.

The following is using sag library for php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('../../src/Sag.php');

//this credentials are from API key
$uName="";
$pName="";

$sag = new Sag('user.cloudant.com');
$sag->login($uName, $pName);
$sag->setDatabase('test');


try {
$result = $sag->get('/test/_design/wordsP/_view/errores');
echo ($result);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
error_log("Something's wrong");
var_dump($e);
}
?>
```

However I'm not getting expected result (). The view does work, if used just in the url bar.

The response is:

```
object(SagException)#3(6){
[
    "message:protected"
]=>string(50)"Sag Error: cURL error #7: couldn't connect to host"[
    "string:private"
]=>string(0)""[
    "code:protected"
]=>int(0)[
    "file:protected"
]=>string(73)"/home2/.../public_html/clant/src/httpAdapters/SagCURLHTTPAdapter.php"[
    "line:protected"
]=>int(134)[
    "trace:private"
]=>array(3){ .............
```

Is there something I'm not using corretly in the php script? (removed current password + username as well as account, but they're there).

Answer (score 0):

Curl error 7 means you are unable to connect to the host or proxy:

> CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)
>
> Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

Source: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

When you connect to the URL from your browser if your browser is using a proxy, you will also need to configure sag to use that proxy.

Also, when you say that you replaced the account in your code example, did you mean that you replaced `user` in `$sag = new Sag('user.cloudant.com');` with your actual username?  If not, you will need to use your actual username.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time.

Indeed I'm using th correct username (the one I can access cloudant with, at least from their own page). 

I will have a look at that link, the browser I'm working with is firefox, hopefully I'll be able to find how to fix this. 

regards.